# Practical understanding of "tapping" into vehicle 12V battery / fusebox for power

Tags: automotive, 12v, fuses, diagram

Disclaimer: I did "tap in" and hooked things to my battery (on my car) many moons ago and did it without really thinking what am I doing, and I was probably doing it in a very hack/ghetto way, but it all worked. Now I'm looking into tapping into this pictured circuit on my bike, and I want to actually understand what happens when I turn the key and fuel pump primes up.

On the fuse box on the bike, first fuse from the top is headlight fuse, which seems like only fuse I can tap into to be able to hook few small devices into the circuit, and all of them being switched only when the key is turned.

I highlighted the headlight bulbs, the first fuse line, and it seems it all goes to relay. May I ask how does a sequence actually go, from turning the key, if we had to slow motion explain how the current flows in that moment, from 12V battery, does it go to the fuse first and then primes the relay that closes the headlight bulb?

I wasn't aware that non-flashing items (like main headlights) are hooked on relay, this is security feature I presume?

I am trying to understand this fully because I plan on running one bulb via Arduino, so it would mean I have to circumvent the current wiring?

[image]

Comment: How would the arduino be powered, all the time or just when key is turned to power up items? What will the Arduino do, why would it only controls a light, but get no input from anywhere? Are you sure the modification with a light you are doing is legal?

Comment: As for legality, that is not a big concern, this is a garage project. Arduino should be on only when the key is turned, I think everything on the bike except from instrument clock is on only when the key is turned. Arduino will control a mosfet - and the mosfet will control the light being on or off.

Comment: The whole point of the relay, is that the keyswitch cannot handle the current needed by the headlamp. So a relay is used, to keep the current in the keyswitch low.

Comment: Just googled up similar explanation - thanks @rdtsc my misconception came from thinking relay = blinkers, turning the repeaters on and off, so I couldn't understand that they could be used for more "serious" use such as being the actual big power switch while the controls are designed more convenient.

So referring to the example I pictured above, I should find a wiring route from actual battery to a node where the relay gets power correct? That should be the fuse box, or something?

Comment: Lower bulb turns on when you turn on the lights. Higher bulb goes through the relay when you switch it from low to hi beam.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you want to do. Are you trying to turn your high beam on via your arduino? What about your high beam switch? Are you trying to use a high side mosfet (switching 12 to 16 volts make sure it doesn't backfeed into your arduino) just tap inbetween the relay contacts you colored purple (power) blue (switched) or a low side mosfet (switching ground) tap into the ground from the high beam bulb if you can thats sometimes grounded through the frame.

Comment: @Passerby the goal is to use all the original buttons - at the moment the plan is to have the high beam bulb controlled by arduino and a nmos - but the more I think about it, the more it seems i should use a mosfet for both bulbs and control them with two mosfets.